# Problems with the integration theorem of stokes.

Tags: calculus, integration

i got problems with the next question:

Let $w(x,y,z) = \left(zx+z^2y+x.z^3xy+y,z^4x^2\right)$ and let $P = P_1 \cup P_2$.

$P_1 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1, z \geq 1 \}$
$P_2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z \geq 1 \}$

Calculate the following integral:

$\iint_S rot(w)\cdot ndA$, where n is the normal vector on P with a non-negative 'z' component, which points away from the z-axis in $P_2$.

I think the main problem for me is to construct the parametrisation of $P$. I see that both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the edges of 2 sphere's with centrums $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$,  but the union doesn't look like a sphere anymore. So spherical coordinates are useless for a parametrization of $P$.

PS: i think $P_2$ is only the point (0,0,1)

The second problem is: Is it easier to solve this question using stokes integration theorem or is it better to just calculate the answer quikly?

tricks/hints/tips would be much appreciated!

Kees

Comment: This is a poor description of the problem.  Please explain what $P_1$ and $P_2$ are more completely.  If they are spheres, what are their radii?  Also, what is $S$?  Why do you think $P_2$ is simply a point?

Comment: srry forgot to write that down i'll do it right away

Comment: There's a typo here somewhere. i'm guessing $P_2$ should be part of a cylinder, not a point.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, how can it be a cilinder? $z \geq 1$ and $x^2+y^2 \geq 0$. So i guessed that the only point that has these condtions was $(0,0,1)$.

I checked my textbook and these sets are exactly like this.